# Assigning task to resource with increased working hours and reduced availability

Tags: ms-project

I am facing a problem when I am assigning a one day task to a resource who works for 9hrs/day but with 25% availability. Following are the steps

1. Created a calendar with 9hrs as working hours (for all days) as shown below

[image]

2. Assigned availability to "Dummy" Resource as shown below

[image: Resource Availability]

3. Created a 1 day task "Dummy" as shown below

[image: Task Allocation]

Problem is

1. Work Column must be 2.25 hrs

   Calculation: Dummy resource for 9hrs/day at 25% availability = (25/100)*9 hrs = 2.25hrs

   but it is showing is 2.13 hrs
2. How to assign a long duration task (say 1 year) to above resource with different availability (as shown in image above). [Note: There are other resource who work for 8hrs/day with different availibility hence I cannot change MS Project "OPTIONS"]
3. I have created 3 calendars - CAL_1, CAL_2 and CAL_3 for 3 different locations. Each location has its own non-working days in each quarter. For example 15 weekdays are not working in Mar, Jun, Sept, Dec in CAL_1 every year. 10 weekdays in same manner for CAL_2 every year and so on. Is there any VBA script by which I can automate such work for every year (note: weekends are not included).

Comment: This is a well-written question that contains almost everything needed to replicate the issue (what is the project calendar?). However, as it is almost exclusively about how MS Project works, and not about programming, the [Project Management](https://pm.stackexchange.com/) site is a better place for it.

Comment: In the meantime, here are quick answers to your questions: 1. I was unable to replicate the exact values you show but also did not get exactly what I expected. 2. When I created a year-long task starting on 1/1/2020 the work for that resource was 2.25h every day even after the resource availability increased, I suspect you would have to manually override--seek advice on the PM site. 3. Yes, with VBA you can modify the Work field.